# How to know if text to speech task has finished in swift

Tags: swift

I have a loop that parse a text string. Unless a line starts with "<" the line is read with text to speech.

```
        for i in text {

            switch i.characters.first {

            case "<"? :

                print("<")

            default:

                readText(String(i))

                sleep(5)

            }

        }
```

Some of the lines spoken are short and others long. I don't want to start reading a line unless the one before has finished. How can I detect when a line is finished reading?

Answer (score 4):

You should use `AVSpeechSynthesizerDelegate`.

1: set your delegate in `viewDidLoad()`

```
let synthesizer = AVSpeechSynthesizer()
synthesizer.delegate = self
```

2: extend your view controller to conform to the `AVSpeechSynthesizerDelegate` protocol and implement the `speechSynthesizer(_:didFinish:)` method

```
extension MyViewController: AVSpeechSynthesizerDelegate {

func speechSynthesizer(synthesizer: AVSpeechSynthesizer, didFinishSpeechUtterance utterance: AVSpeechUtterance) {
        print("speech finished")
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you! I will try that. I guess there's one "let" to many on your second line?

Comment: Yes, sorry for secon line "let". I've edited the answer and fixed it. :)